# how to prepare data format to show in c3js chart?

Tags: php, charts

I want to show percent of department depend on date in c3js chart with timeseries.

I have four department id, and I query the result like this.

```
$dept_id_arr = array();
$date_arr = array();
$percent_arr =  array();
$sql = ........;
$rsl = mysql_query($sql);
while($get = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsl)){
    $date_arr[] = $get['date'];
    $dept_id_arr[] = $get['department_id'];
    $percent_arr[] = $get['total_percent'];
}
```

When I print this data with var_dump(), I got like this,

```
string(66) "["2015-11-17","2015-11-17","2015-11-18","2015-11-20","2015-11-23"]"

string(22) "["1","3","1","1","2"]"

string(46) "["0.5700","0.0000","0.5700","0.0000","0.5700"]"
```

I want to change that value to like this,

```
[{
        "date": "2015-11-17",
        "department1": "0.5",
        "department2": "0.9",
        "department3": "4",
        "department4": "3",
    }, {
        "date": "2015-11-18",
        "department1": "0.5",
        "department2": "0",
        "department3": "0",
        "department4": "0",
    }, {
        "date": "2015-11-19",
        "department1": "0.5",
        "department2": "0.3",
        "department3": "5",
        "department4": "2",
    }]
```

because I need to show that data in c3js chart. But I have problem, when I change data to that format because of some date are same in array.

Comment: What is `departmentNUM`?

Comment: I want to show department id as like this :  `department`  is only text and `NUM` is dynamic department id from database.

Comment: Which type of chart are you using for c3js

Comment: You can do like this

`$date = ["2015-11-17","2015-11-17","2015-11-18","2015-11-20","2015-11-23"];
$departmeent = ["1","3","1","1","2"];
$percentage = ["0.5700","0.0000","0.5700","0.0000","0.5700"];
$array = array();

for($i=0; $i<5;$i++)
{

 array_push($array, array('date' => $date[$i], 
     'department' => $departmeent[$i],
     'per' => $percentage[$i]

  ));
 
}

echo var_dump($array);`

Comment: This is the same format now I get. I mean is, I want to group department id and percentage if they are same date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do all the things by this code:

```
<?php
$date = ["2015-11-17","2015-11-17","2015-11-18","2015-11-20","2015-11-23"];
$departmeent = ["1","3","1","1","2"];
$percentage = ["0.5700","0.0000","0.5700","0.0000","0.5700"];
$array = array();

for($i=0; $i<5;$i++)
{
    if(array_key_exists($date[$i], $array))
    {
        $array[$date[$i]]['department'.$departmeent[$i]]= $departmeent[$i];
        $array[$date[$i]]['per'.$departmeent[$i]]= $percentage[$i];

    }
    else
    {

        $array[$date[$i]] = array('department'.$departmeent[$i] => $departmeent[$i],
                    'per'.$departmeent[$i] => $percentage[$i]) ;
    }   

}

echo var_dump($array["2015-11-17"]["department1"]);

echo '<br><br><br><br><br><br>'.json_encode($array);
?>
```